# Is it bad practice to have a function that doesn't return if it throws an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some computational functions for configurations for software that will drive a hardware setup. In some cases, the user may input invalid configuration values. I handle this by throwing an exception if invalid values are used, or simply returning my calculated value if the configuration works:

```
def calc_exhale_dur(breath_rate, inh_dur, breath_hold_dur):
    """Calculate exhalation duration.

    Args:
        breath_rate (float): animal breath rate (br/min)
        inh_dur (float): animal inhalation duration (ms)
        breath_hold_duration (float): animal breath hold duration (ms)
    """

    single_breath_dur = calc_breath_dur(breath_rate)
    exhale_dur = single_breath_dur - (inh_dur + breath_hold_dur)

    if (inh_dur + breath_hold_dur + exhale_dur) > single_breath_dur:
        raise error.ConfigurationError
    elif exhale_dur <= 0:
        raise error.ConfigurationError
    else:
        return exhale_dur
```

Is it considered bad practice to do it this way? Do I always need to have some valid return value if there is a return value to begin with? I'm trying to learn how best to write Pythonic code while still satisfying the needs of my computational methods.

Comment: What's the point of returning something if it is throwing an exception. ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of raising an exception is to provide an alternate exit point in the event where a valid return value can't be found. You are using exceptions exactly as they are intended.

However, I would probably check if `exhale_dir` is non-positive first, which would save you from performing a calculation with an invalid value.

```
if exhale_dur <= 0:
    raise error.ConfigurationError
elif (inh_dur + breath_hold_dur + exhale_dur) > single_breath_dur):
    raise error.ConfigurationError

# You can also omit the else, since the only way to reach this point
# is to *not* have raised an exception. This is a matter of style, though.
return exhale_dur
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This answers my specific question more completely than the posted duplicate answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. Exceptions are either handled in a piece of code, or thrown, and leave it to the caller to decide what to do with them. If you return something, you *have to* choose the first option. You chose the second. Makes perfect sense. That's the whole idea of throwing an exception